# Consolidating and pivoting multiple years data in Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I currently have a large amount of Excel data that is laid out with 'Country' and 'Series' as the row headings, and various years (1960-2012) as individual column headings. I want to pivot the data so I have 'Country' and 'Year' as the row headings and the various series as the column headings. How can I consolidate the years (1960-2012) so I can create a pivot table like this? Thanks

Comment: You can unpivot your data by following these steps: http://www.launchexcel.com/pivot-table-flatten-crosstab/  Then you can pivot it by the required fields.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue with this is that my flattened (unpivoted) table is laid out with the 'Row' col containing the various countries, the 'Column' col containing the various years, & the 'Value' col containing both the various series headers & the data values - so when I try to re-pivot this, I cannot separate-out the series names as column headings from the actual data values. I assume this is because I started out with two columns of row headings ('Country' and 'Series').

Comment: hello @user1608180, any possibility of you posting a screenshot of the current data? Or even just a small sample of what it looks like and the output expected? I'm thinking you may be able to solve this with VBA.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm trying to get from and to: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/541559/Temp/Pivot.PNG

Comment: my answer will get you to the point where you can get your desired layout through a pivot.

Comment: The depivot step will work if you first concatenate your two row-label columns into one (you can split them back out after the depivot)

Comment: @nutsch Thanks! That worked. Tim Williams: Thanks, but concatenating two dimensions that I ultimately want on two different axes won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unpivoting using my unpivot add-in here: http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/the-unpivot-add-in/